# Find the time taken for the downstream journey given the following conditions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> A boat travels from point P to point Q upstream and returns from point Q to point P downstream PQ=$96$ Km.If the round trip takes $9$ hrs and speed of boat in still water is 8Kmph more than the speed of the stream,find the time taken for the downstream journey?

MyApproach:

options

a)$3$Kmph

b)$3$Kmph

c)$6$Kmph

d)$8$Kmph

MyApproach:

Given PQ=$96$

Speed in still water=$8$+speed in stream

Therefore,Upstream speed=8kmph

Given,Upstream time + Downstream time=$9$

$96$/8+Downstream time=9

=>Downstream time=-3hrs

I am getting Ans as -3.

> I don't know what I am doing Wrong?Can Anyone guide me how to solve the Problem?